# i want to make a search in which i can search upper case and lower case both at same time..?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

the problem statement is i have to make a search function in which i can search lower can upper case element both even if i type lower case either upper case

i tried upper case search and lower case but its not working at all please suggest me as soon as possible

```
search(searchValue) {
    if (searchValue != null && searchValue != "") {
      var searchItem = searchValue;
      var allOppData = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData;

      var filtered = _.mapValues(allOppData, statuses =>
        _.filter(statuses, statusT =>
          _.some(statusT, T => _.includes(T, searchItem))
        )
      );
      this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData = filtered;
      let stages = this.opportunitiesStateReason;
      stages.forEach(element => {
        let num = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData[element.orderData].reduce(
          function(sum, value) {
            return sum + value.expected_revenue;
          },
          0
        );
        element.totalExpectedRevenue = num.toFixed(2);
      });
    } else {
      this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesDataCopy;
      let stages = this.opportunitiesStateReason;
      stages.forEach(element => {
        let num = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData[element.orderData].reduce(
          function(sum, value) {
            return sum + value.expected_revenue;
          },
          0
        );
        element.totalExpectedRevenue = num.toFixed(2);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: give us some example and expected output

Comment: for example if there is table with a element name test so if i search (Test,TEST,test) it has to show the result
test
exactly same functionality 
https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts

Comment: you haven't returned anything in your search function. is that the error?

Comment: return sum + value.expected_revenue;
i have returned this

Comment: ok that return is not correct. let me add my solution in the answer. I think that might be your solution

Comment: its now working let me show you some screenshot so you understand better

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.  you have missed to return the for the `search` function.

**NOTE:** you have only returned for a function inside `search` function

```js
function search(searchValue) {
    if (searchValue != null && searchValue != "") {
        var searchItem = searchValue;
        var allOppData = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData;

        var filtered = _.mapValues(allOppData, statuses =>
            _.filter(statuses, statusT =>
                _.some(statusT, T => _.includes(T, searchItem))
            )
        );
        this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData = filtered;
        let stages = this.opportunitiesStateReason;
        return stages.forEach(element => {
            let num = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData[element.orderData].reduce(
                function(sum, value) {
                    return sum + value.expected_revenue;
                },
                0
            );
            element.totalExpectedRevenue = num.toFixed(2);
        });
    } else {
        this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesDataCopy;
        let stages = this.opportunitiesStateReason;
        return stages.forEach(element => {
            let num = this.stagesWiseOpportunitiesData[element.orderData].reduce(
                function(sum, value) {
                    return sum + value.expected_revenue;
                },
                0
            );
            element.totalExpectedRevenue = num.toFixed(2);
        });
    }
}

console.log(search("Test"))
```